# Question about parity of Pythagorean triples

Tags: divisibility, pythagorean-triples

I want to show that if $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{N}^+\times \mathbb{N}^+\times \mathbb{N}^+$ is a Pythagorean triple with $gcd(a,b,c)=1$ then $a$ and $b$ cannot simultaniously be odd.

Reducing modulo $4$ gives an easy and quick way to show this but I would like to show it without modulo reduction (I mean this exercise is in Beachy and Blair: Abstract algebra, and the whole congruence class story is in the next chapter)

Any HINTS for me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You do not need $gcd(a,b,c)=1$. The claim is also true for non-primitive triples.

Comment: Why don't you want to use modular arithmetic although it gives an easy and quick solution ? You do not need heavy calculations, just a square modulo $4$.

Comment: It says in the parenthesis. I am solving all the exercises in the above named book, I already took a course using this book so I solved some of the exercises during the course but not all, now I would like to solve all of them and I would like to use the chapters "knowledge" to do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume $a=2n+1$ and $b=2m+1$ and use $a^2+b^2=c^2$ taking two cases, one assuming $c=2p$ and another assuming that $c=2p+1$. Contradictions will arise.

Comment: I think I have been there already but I will keep trying then :)
thank you

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa Where have you been already? I don't understand properly 

Comment: I meant I have already tried something like that but I thought it was a wrong approach :)

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa No, It's perfectly fine. You can prove using this.

Comment: @Peter Kind of... but a person who knows nothing about modular airthmetic can also use this technique to prove these kind of problems.

Comment: ohh. now I see. I just didn't follow through with the idea, I was thinking too fast and therefore I missed that the left hand side is not divisible by $4$ whereas the right hand side does. Thank you! Here comes in the moduli 4 reduction. Nice! :)

Comment: If $a=2n+1$, then $b\ne2m+1$.  Try  $b=4m$